# FFMPEG Merge two videos into one with side-by-side same quality output

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm already working on project with 3d video and I have a problem, I got left and right channel of video and I need to merge them into side by side. I already read some blogs about this problem and I got this code:

```
ffmpeg -i avatar35l.avi -vf "movie=avatar35r.avi [in1]; [in]pad=1920*2:1080[in0]; [in0][in1] overlay=1920:0 [out]" avatar35sbs.avi
```

It works, but there is significant quality loss and I need the quality of the output video to be the same as the input video: 30fps, 1080p, same length. I'm new to `ffmpeg` and i need a concrete example of that.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Lossless

You'll have to use a truly lossless format if you require "a quality of output video same as input video". Example for ffv1 using the [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) filter instead of movie+pad+overlay:

```
ffmpeg -i left.avi -i right.avi -filter_complex hstack -c:v ffv1 output.avi
```

FFmpeg supports several additional lossless compressed formats such as:

- lossless H.264: `-c:v libx264 -crf 0`
- huffyuv: `-c:v huffyuv`
- ffvhuff: `-c:v ffvhuff`
- UT Video: `-c:v utvideo`
- And of course lossless uncompressed formats including rawvideo.

Since it is lossless the output file will be huge, and your player or device will probably not like it.

## Visually lossless

Of course what you may actually want is "lossy, yet 'visually lossless', but not a gigantic, huge file like true lossless provides". In that case use:

```
ffmpeg -i left.avi -i right.avi -filter_complex "hstack,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 output.mp4
```

You didn't mention audio. If you want to merge the audio from each input as well use the [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i left.avi -i right.avi -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack,format=yuv420p[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -ac 2 output.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: [AVFilterGraph @ 026d1760] No such filter: 'hstack'
Error configuring filters.
Conversion failed!