# Merge videos with different start times and show them on a grid

Tags: video, merge, ffmpeg

I have multiple video files of a conference call. However, each participant joined the call at a different time, which resulted in the fact that each video file has a different start time offset values.

```
Video   Start Time
------------------
Video1  00:00
Video2  00:10
Video3  01:40
```

My purpose is to play back this conference. However, I did not record the conference as 1 video, it is recorded with multiple video files, instead.
How do I stitch these videos?

There is also [a paid solution](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/amazon-elastic-transcoder-adds-support-for-clip-stitching/) to merge video fragments to a single clip – this will make the client-side much simpler. But can I do it for free?

The expected outcome is to have one video showing three videos on a grid.
When ffmpeg stitches the videos, it should consider their start time values properly so that the videos are played accordingly.

Comment: The question is not clear. By merging, you mean concatenating one after the other? Do they have audio? Do they have the same codec etc.? What have you tried yet?

Comment: @slhck, is it now?  
Is there any stich function in ffmpeg to handle it by giving the start time values as a parameter?  What is the best practice to do it in an efficient way when it comes to stitching together two or more input clips 3 videos (with 200mb) .

Comment: It's clearer now, thanks. Use the `-itsoffset` option for each input file. Then you need a filter that overlays each video onto a background of a certain color.

Comment: Here's another start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255139/ffmpeg-merge-two-videos-into-one-with-side-by-side-same-quality-output

Answer (score 4):

Use `-itsoffset` to specify the offset (in `s.msec`) of the individual streams. The value will be subtracted from / added to the timestamps of the individual streams. Obviously, you have to play around with the offset depending on your input streams.

For example:

```
ffmpeg \
-itsoffset -1 -i video.mp4 \
-itsoffset -2 -i video.mp4 \
-itsoffset -3 -i video.mp4 \
-filter_complex hstack=inputs=3 \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 out.mp4
```

This gives you video streams stacked next to each other using the [`hstack` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack), offset by a second each.

[image]

You can also use a complex filterchain to [generate a black background color](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc), e.g. with 1280×720 size and a 10 s duration, then [overlay](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) the stacked videos, and [merge](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge-1) the audio streams:

```
ffmpeg \
-itsoffset -1 -i video.mp4 \
-itsoffset -2 -i video.mp4 \
-itsoffset -3 -i video.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
"color=c=black:s=1280x720:d=10[black]; \
[0:v][1:v][2:v]hstack=inputs=3[stacked]; \
[0:a][1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=3[outa]; \
[black][stacked]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 output.mp4
```

[image]

Comment: `-itsoffset -1 ` --> you are subtracting 1 from stored PTS. If they start at 0, then a second's worth will get cut. If the streams have STARTPTS baked in, then `-vsync 0` should do the trick.